# Programatically get Python cflags and libs for compiling C extension

Tags: python, c, cython

**Prelude**

In linux one can run:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs python3
```

and get as result:

```
-I/usr/include/python3.5m -lpython3.5m
```

**Problem**

I want to get this result programatically from a Python script in both Linux and Windows.

**Motivation**

I have several Python scripts that I want to compile as C using cython. I'm trying to create a Python script that would handle this compilation process.

Having three files: `exec.py`, `apkg.py`, `bpkg.py`; the desired execution order would be:

1. `cython --embed exec.py`
2. `cython apkg.py`
3. `cython bpkg.py`
4. `gcc -shared -fPIC -O3 -I/usr/include/python3.5m -lpython3.5m apkg.c -o apkg.so`
5. `gcc -shared -fPIC -O3 -I/usr/include/python3.5m -lpython3.5m bpkg.c -o bpkg.so`
6. `gcc -c -O3 -I/usr/include/python3.5m -lpython3.5m exec.c`
7. `gcc -o exec exec.o`

And `exec` would be a compiled executable that needs apkg.so and bpkg.so in the same directory to run.

**Posible answers**

- Use `python-config`: as of version 3.5, the Python installer for Windows (tried in 64 bits) does not include `python-config`
- User `pkg-config`: again, Windows compatibility issue.

Comment: Well yes windows is a bi****h, do you know about *cmake*?

Comment: I know about cmake, I could create a custom command for the cython phase but... to find Python wouldn't it need pkg-config?

Comment: Well not necessarily, python is installed in a known location on Windows AFAIK. And probably *cygwin* or *MinGW* ship *pkg-config* with them.

Comment: Actually, that location changed from version 3.4 to 3.5 (C:\ to C:\Program Files). I'm trying to avoid all this and find a standard way to do it from a simple Python script

Comment: Well I just tried to guide you in a very general way. I am not an expert, but I believe there is some *setuptools* module shipped with every python distribution, it might be what you need.

Comment: [Check here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).